# Как клонировать элемент в WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть ресурс

```
<Application.Resources>
        <TextBlock x:Key="Block"
                   Height="31"
                   Background="AliceBlue"
                   Text=""
                   TextWrapping="Wrap">

        </TextBlock>
</Application.Resources>
```

Потом динамически хочу сформировать страницу, несколько раз втавив данный элемент на страницу, но с разным текстом.

```
TextBlock block = Application.Current.Resources["PurchaseBlock"] as TextBlock
block.Text = "Заказ 1";
PageStack.Children.Add(block);
block.Text = "Заказ 2";
PageStack.Children.Add(block);
```

Но это не работает, так как элемент второй раз не вставляется на страницу, после того как был  вставлен первый раз. Так вот: можно ли по ходу программы клонировать этот элемент? В дальнейшем я его расширю, это сейчас он простой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно используете WPF. Вам следует положить строки в коллекцию `ObservableCollection<string> Items`, добавить на страницу `<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding Items}>`, управлять отображением строк с помощью `DataTemplate` для элементов списка, а относительным расположением — с помощью `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`, стиль текстового элемента при этом можно выделить в отдельный `Style`.

Клонировать элементы можно с помощью добавления в ресурсы с `x:Shared=False` и последующим извлечением из ресурсов, но это не то, что вам надо.

Советую вам почитать про MVVM. Использовать WPF как WinForms — неправильно и очень сложно. В подавляющем большинстве случаев у вас не должно возникать желания ничего клонировать и вручную добавлять на страницу.

Comment: Жаль, что комментарии в стиле «+1» запрещены.

Comment: Я так понимаю, чтобы использовать `<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding Items}> ` надо установить `this.DataContext = this;`, так? И как мне поставить обработчики на элементы списка? Мне надо обрабатывать клик по каждому элементу, а в `DataTemplate` обработчик вставить можно ли?

Comment: @RussCoder Вью-модель — обычно отдельный класс, поэтому обычно `this.DataContext = new FooViewModel()`, либо аналогичный код в XAML, либо при создании вьюхи извне, либо при помощи DI и т. п. В мелких проектах в качестве грязного хака можно запихнуть свойства вью-модели прямо во вьюху, но это неканонично, ибо нарушение SRP. / Обработчики можно добавить в шаблон и code-behind. Но это опять неканонично, по-нормальному нужно добавлять обработчики в VM либо в виде методов, либо в виде команд. / Советую воспользоваться библиотекой MVVM вроде Caliburn.Micro, жизнь будет проще. И почитайте про MVVM.

Comment: @Discord ну вообщем я понял, что ничего не знаю. Буду благодарен, если Вы мне книгу назовете или сайт какой про MVVM, весьма желательно на русском.

Comment: @RussCoder Никогда не читал ничего на русском. Где-то на СО.РУ валяется вопрос про книги, там что-то полезное должно быть.